# Simulating SIM card functions for android VMs

Tags: android, function, virtual, simulate

I have my VM (virtual machine) install Android OS. How can I simulate a SIM card functions in the VM?
Let's say, 
- Where could I buy a device that can "virtualize" a real-physical SIM into virtual-SIM for my android VM to use (to send SMS, or even make a phone call, etc)
- Or do you know any software (opensource) that could simulate a SIM card functions?

Thanks so much. All comments are appreciated!

Comment: You can install genymotion emulator https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/

Answer (score 1):

You can make fake call from adb.
Following command i am testing adb with genimotion emulator.

Get serial Number
$adb get-serialno

Find serial number and replace it

```
$adb -s serial-number shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:555-5555
```

mac pc:

```
$./adb -s serial-number shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:555-5555
```

Comment: Thank you. How about the sms function? Actually I'm more interested in this one, and I expect to have it worked on VM (for example: android OS installed on Virtualbox, VMware, KVM, etc)

Comment: @Hermant 
Let's say I have an android Virtual Machine created by Cloudstack on KVM. Is there any technique that I could simulate the sim functions (SMS for example) for that android VM?

Or, can I connect the VM to a real SIM card to take advantage of its functionality- what can I do to achieve this?